# My program overwrites the file it is writing into, but it shouldn't

Tags: java, file, append, overwrite

I have this program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Oblig2 {

public static void main (String[] args) {
final Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int menyvalg=0;
Meny menyen = new Meny();   
menyen.meny(); 
}
}   
//Selve menyen til programmet i en egen klasse.

class Meny {

PrintWriter fil;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);    

public void meny() {
try{
    fil=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Filen finnes ikke");
} 


int menyvalg=0;
int menykall=1; 
//Menyen vil her bli repetert helt til en taster inn 4 og endrer menykall til 0.
do{
    //Selve menyen vil bli repetert helt til brukeren velger en av menyens alternativer.
    do{
    System.out.println("====== Meny for registrering av fugleobservasjoner =====");

    System.out.println("\n1. Registrer en fugleobservasjon");
    System.out.println("2. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner av en type");
    System.out.println("3. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner på ett bestemt sted");
    System.out.println("4. Avslutt systemet");

    System.out.println("\nVennligst velg en aksjon: ");
    menyvalg = input.nextInt();

        } while(menyvalg < 1 || menyvalg > 4);

    switch (menyvalg){
    case 1: registrering();
    break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        case 4:menykall=0;
        }
    }while(menykall>=1); 
  }

void registrering () {

System.out.println("Velkommen til registreringen av fugleobservasjoner.");
System.out.println("Begynner registreringen (Lagrer seg i filen fugler.txt): ");

    try { 
    fil = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt", true));

    System.out.println("\nVennligst tast inn fugletypen: ");
        String fugletype = input.next();
        fil.write(fugletype + ","); 

    System.out.println("Tast inn fuglens kjonn (M/H/X): ");
    char fuglekjonn = input.next().charAt(0);
    fil.write(fuglekjonn + ",");

    System.out.println("Tast inn observasjonslokasjon: ");
    String lokasjon = input.next();
    fil.write(lokasjon + ",");

    System.out.println("Tast inn dato for observasjon (Som en string på formen mai2012): ");
    String dato = input.next();
    fil.write(dato);

    fil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Åpning av fil feilet");
    }
  }
 }
```

And when I run it, and then through case 1 which is a script for registering information into a .txt file called fugler.txt. Te problem is that everytime I register a new bird into this I want it to get placed nice and sweetly at the end of the file. But it doesn't. it overwrites the entire file. And why does it do that, when I have placed true at the end of the opening of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Following Lines in your program

```
try{
    fil=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Filen finnes ikke");
}
```

As it is creates a new file everytime it executes.

Comment: Thanks alot. You are my god. So many hours spent, and finally an answer... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this constructor [with append parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
fil = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt", true));
```

make this as

```
fil = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt", false));
```